# Opencart page won't redirect

Tags: php, opencart, 3d-secure

I made a custom payment gateway which works. Now I have integrated 3D secure into the gateway and am having a hard time re-directing after confirming the order.

I have tried using

```
$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
```

also

```
$this->redirect($url);
```

as well as

```
$this->redirect($this->url->link($url)); //shortened $url
```

I have also written my own custom redirect functions, forced html meta refresh into the code and still no dice.

What about errors... I am getting no errors whatsoever except for once when I directly called the php header('location:') and got a headers already sent error. I have also plugged in my very own error logging/tracking code I get information that the functions are in fact executing.

I know the extension works because manually plugging in in the relevant links directly into the browser gives me results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to use the redirect from within an iframe or something along those lines?

Comment: No I am not. I am trying to call a re-direct from directly within the controller.

Comment: If you are redirecting right after the **setOutput** and you called that method from javascript, of course it will not work. Send some response url variable in **$json** and redirect with javascript.

Comment: Look at other payment services's source code. In the `callback` or `confirm` methods they are redirecting, too - so check what's different from what You have done and try to repair it so the PHP redirect would work...

Comment: I tried redirecting using javaScript from within the view by creating a session on the url and using isset. Some new light has also been shed also - I realized I have been fiddling with a function that I have no clue where it is called. Any Idea where the send() or callback functions in the payment modules are being called?

Answer (score 0):

If your code was worked manually, you can use javascript redirect instead of php header redirect function.

```
<script> window.location = '<?php echo $this->url->link($url); ?>' </script>
```

Sometimes, header redirect sometimes can not work if page encoding is not suitable or get an error, etc. Javascript redirect worked for me in the same situation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I created a new view file and tried calling  the template configuration code within the controller (seen this method used in the WorldPay payment extension).     ` if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/payment/pay_send.tpl')) {
    $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/payment/pay_send.tpl';
   } else {
    $this->template = 'default/template/payment/pay_send.tpl';
   }
   
   $this->response->setOutput($this->render());    ` Still did not work though. sorry for bad formatting of comment :(

Comment: @machineaddict I changed this line in the view

    if (json['success']) {
        location = json['success'];
    }

to 

    if (json['success']) {
        window.location = json['success'];
    }

and it now re-directs. Thank you Jesus.

Now However, it seems to redirect to "index.php?route=" even though the full url {"success":"http:\/\/my_site\/index.php?route=checkout\/checkout"} is being passed. 

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: solution is in your controller file. Send full url in json's success element from controller. You can use `$this->url->link('checkout/checkout')` or etc.